# Mulitple Elements with the same ID

Tags: javascript, video, getelementbyid

I am trying to use a script on three videos using the same ID (#vid) on the same page. At the moment only one video seems to be able to use the script.

```
var video = document.getElementById('vid')
// When the 'ended' event fires
video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
  // Reset the video to 
  video.currentTime = 0;
  // And play again
  video.load();
});
```

Comment: `id` should be unique, otherwise only first one get selected

Comment: Thanks Pranav, how do I modify this?

Comment: attach class to your elements

Comment: If you want to use on multiple elements, try using class instead of id

Comment: Tried using a class but the script doesn't seem to work on all 3 videos

Comment: Yoyu can not bind to an html collection, you would need to loop over it....

Comment: hmm, can you post the code for your HTML elements? Pranav's got you covered below.

Comment: You need to add loop so you can attach event to all the elements of same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these answers are only partially correct.

For your **markup** to be valid, **id's need to be be unique**. However, sometimes careless developers re-use the same id in the DOM. Fear not, it isn't the end of the world, you can still access multiple elements with the same id as you might using classes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#vid');
```

Will return a HTMLCollection (array like object) of elements with the same id.

Comment: This is a bad practice and should not be encouraged. This answer is merely a band-aid

Comment: @j08691 It's absolutely terrible practice. I don't recommend it as something that SHOULD be done. I do point out that it's invalid HTML and bolded ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 5):

`Id` must be unique. You should use `class` instead and then make use of `document.getElementsByClassName('className');`

```
var video = document.getElementsByClassName('vid');
var myFunction = function() {
    // Reset the video to 
    this.currentTime = 0;
    // And play again
    this.load();
};

for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    video[i].addEventListener('ended', myFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: @epascarello Yes I get that, I have edited the code to loop to individual elements, made a mistake earlier

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute should be unique otherwise only the first one gets selected always. So use `class` for a group of elements and iterate over them to attach the event handler.

```
<script>
  var video = document.getElementsByClassName('vid');
  // convert the element collection to array using Array.from()
  // for older browser use `[].slice.call()` for converting into array
  // and iterate over the elements to attach listener
  Array.from(video).forEach(function(v) {
    v.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      v.currentTime = 0; // or use `this` to refer the element
      v.load();
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is not supported in IE. So either needs polyfill or a for loop.

Comment: @epascarello :  added alternative in comment

Comment: @epascarello: oh, IE...it is supported in Edge apparently ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility)); and a shim is as simple as `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)` so it's not a huge problem, really.

Comment: FYI: typo getElementsByClassname should be getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

IDs can only be used once in a document and they should be unique. What you shold do instead is give them a class and then target that class and run the function on every item with that class.

Example give them a class="vid"

```
<script>

var videos = document.getElementsByClassName('vid');
// When the 'ended' event fires


for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('ended', function(){
    // Reset the video to 
    videos[i].currentTime = 0;
    // And play again
    videos[i].load();
   });
}

</script>
```

I'm not sure this exact code works with the event listener adding but the concept is right.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same identifier more than ones is invalid markup and as `getElementById` only returns a single element it will return the first one it comes across.

However, if you are not able to change the markup using your existing scenario exactly as is you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all element with the same `id` attribute value.

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('[id="vid"]')

for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('ended', function() {
        // Reset the video to 
        video.currentTime = 0;
        // And play again
        video.load();
    });
}
```

---

> However, if you can you should use other means to identify the elements, such as data attributes or classes.
>
> Personally I'm leaning towards data attributes for functional use and leave classes for CSS use.
>
> That way their uses stay exclusive and UI devs changing
> classes/css won't impact your functional code as they should not change
> attributes and vice versa.