# How do I get the values of an appended element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a calculator that takes multiple time inputs and I need to get the values of a created div element that has been appended.

this is the code for the appended element

```
let div - document.createElement("div"); 
div.innerHTML = html; 
schedule.appendChild(div.firstElementChild);
```

this is the code for the html element being created:

```
<div class = "times"> 
 <input id = "start" type = "time" value = ""> 
 <input id = "end" type = "time"  value = ""> 
</div>
```

I need to get the value of the time inputs that are being created by the JavaScript code, in JavaScript. How do I do this?

Comment: The same way you get any other element's value. `document.getElementById("start").value`

Comment: so, document.getElementById("start").value gets the value for the input with the ID of "start." I already did that. I need the value of the div of the element that was created from the html code and appended to the document, so unfortunately your comment isn't very helpful.

Comment: A div doesn't have a value, only inputs do.

Comment: You can save `div.firstElementChild` in a variable, then use `thatVariable.value`

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you really want from a very incomplete description.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the lack of details or [mcve] are the reason why others did.

Comment: I don't really care about the down votes. The code I used is the code I need help with. I don't know how else to explain it, but I am sure someone else who can actually help will.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "value of the div of the element". There are two inputs in the DIV, which one's value do you want? It doesn't get a value until the user enters something into it, do you have an event listener waiting for that?

Comment: Is the HTML created dynamically, so you don't know what ID the inputs will get? It's really hard to tell what the context of this is, which is why we request a [mcve].

Comment: I need the values of BOTH inputs, as they are time inputs. There are two of them because one is a start time and one is an end time, hence the ID names. The HTML code WAS NOT created dynamically. It is written in HTML, which is why I included that it is the html code. The JavaScript code takes the div that these input elements are nested in, creates a new input element and appends that element to the HTML document on the click of a button, which is why I added that the code is the JS code. If the JS code copied the HTML code exactly, the id of the inputs should be "start" and "end"

Comment: however, the values of those inputs are not stored in those IDs. I don't know where they are stored, which is why I asked how do I get the values of an appended element?

Comment: Where is `html` coming from? If you're copying it from the `innerHTML` of some other element, you're creating duplicate IDs in the DOM, which is why `getElementById()` isn't working.

Comment: You can use `div.querySelectorAll('input')` to get a list of all the inputs in `div`.

Comment: You can then loop over them to get their values.

Comment: So, get element by id is working. I can get the values of the "start" and "end" inputs using get element by id. I need to know how to get the values of the inputs that JavaScript is creating. THAT is being copied from the innerHTML and I need to know where the values of those inputs are in order to "get" them. I mean, it literally says div.innerHTML, so I'm assuming you'd be able to read the code and know what is going on without needing all the details.

Comment: I really don't mean to sound crass, but I am self-learning JavaScript, so Im not sure how else to explain this to you. I'm really just trying to get some help with my project and hoping to learn as I go.

Comment: There's nothing different about getting the values of inputs that are created by JS. If you know the IDs, and the IDs are unique, you use `getElementsById()`. If the IDs are not unique, you have a design problem.

Comment: It's passed my bedtime and I have to work at 7 am, so I will try the query selector tomorrow. appreciate your time and input (no pun intended)

Comment: Consider using classes instead of IDs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831645/mulitple-elements-with-the-same-id

Answer (score 0):

I think what I understood and what you need is the code below. . .check it out and let me know your thoughts. . .. when you slect time the **onchange** event will trigger and the value will be append as"<p>"tag to it's parent div. if you want you can append the value to body also. . .

```js
let div1 = document.createElement("div"); 
const html1=`
<div class = "times" style='border:1px solid red;width:300px;height:100px;padding:10px;margin:5px;'> 
 <input onchange='change(this)' type = "time" value = "" /> 
 <input onchange='change(this)' type = "time"  value = "" /> 
</div> 
`;
div1.innerHTML = html1; 
let div2 = document.createElement("div"); 
const html2=`
<div class = "times" style='border:1px solid red;width:300px;height:100px;padding:10px;margin:5px;'> 
 <input onchange='change(this)' type = "time" value = "" /> 
 <input onchange='change(this)' type = "time"  value = "" /> 
</div> 
`;
div2.innerHTML = html2; 
let schedule=document.getElementById("schedule");
schedule.appendChild(div1); 
schedule.appendChild(div2); 

function change(e){
    let par=e.parentNode;
    let p=document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML=`${e.value}`;
    par.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="schedule" style="border:1px solid blue;width:500px;height:300px;padding:20px;">
 shedule div
</div>
```

Comment: So, I'm self-learning JavaScript and I don't understand most of what is in this code, can you please explain exactly what each section of code does so I can see if this is what I am asking? I do know that it takes some effort to explain the code. I really am just trying to learn JS and want to understand the language in depth. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, why is there CSS code in there? I don't need the CSS code. The borders aren't how I want my boxes styled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Check all the id  values in the html to make sure no two elements with the same id. Follow your javaScript logic to make sure you don't append children with the same id.